# Отображение вложенных списков, с закрепление текста в блоке?

Tags: javascript

[image: так должно отображаться]Мной реализованы табы, в которых отображаются списки, в некоторых со вложенностями. Проблема в правильном отображении. В первом активном табе, при клике на вложенный список Здания(серым выделены вложенные списки) его список отображается и нужно, чтобы все остальные ссылки ( кот, собака, жираф) и в том числе Здания скрывались, а слово Здания появлялось под Таб 1(там выделен блок, для добавления названий вложенных списков по которым был переход, с классом pinned). Дальше еще вложенный список Школа, при клике на нее предыдущий вложенный список и Школа скрывались, слово школа закреплялась под Таб 1(т.е там уже два слова Здания , Школа) и так далее и возможность перехода обратно(т.е кликаем на слово под табом и переходим на соответствующий список.
Если в любом из табов был открыт вложенный список, он должен закрепляться под соответствующим табом. Не доходит как это реализовать...

[смотреть здесь][https://jsfiddle.net/YulyaYulya/gnshpb2u/82/]

Comment: Вот вы знаете, я бы вообще по другому такую затею исполнял. Написал бы функции, которые генерируют html-коды этих списков табов и ссылок на js из вложенных массивов. А другая функция бы ловила клик по ссылкам и меняла бы содержимое html под табами динамически. А с вашей архитектурой нужно раз за разом читать html, парсить его обратно до списка и снова генерировать html -- двойная работа!

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку как лучше сделать

Comment: Успехов в изучении JS! :)